# Rails: How can I call a controller's create action without changing views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, routes, rake

I have a view, `views/admin/index.html.erb`, that has a button on it that I created with the following...

**views/admin/index.html.erb**

```
<%= button_to 'Manual Scrape', {:controller => "jobs", :action => "create", :job_type => "StatsAll"}, :method=>:post, :class => "btn btn-primary"  %>
```

**controllers/jobs_controller.rb**

```
  def create

    call_rake :import_records, :job_type => params[:job_type]
    flash[:notice] = "Import is executing..."

  end
```

**controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
  def call_rake(task, options = {})
    options[:rails_env] = Rails.env
    args = options.map { |n, v| "#{n.to_s.upcase}='#{v}'" }
    system "/usr/bin/rake #{task} #{args.join(' ')} --trace >> #{Rails.root}/log/rake.log &"
  end
```

When I click the button I would like it to remain on the current view which is, `views/admin/index.html.erb`, since I don't have a jobs view and don't believe I want one (maybe someone will convince me otherwise...).  What I am trying to do is click the button and then on that view I will change the button to one that will call another action on the `jobs_controller.rb` to kill the job if necessary, otherwise it will execute until it completes.

However currently it tries to find the jobs view, which there is none.  How can I correct this?

Note: I've used some of the code from Railscast #127 to see how to run a background task.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this with some JavaScript/AJAX if you don't want to reload the page. First and foremost, I assume you have a path for your jobs controller for the jobs function? Find out by doing `rake routes` and see where your POST, not the GET for the create function in your jobs controller. I think you've made it this far to have it already there.

For your view, change it to:

```
<%= button_to 'Manual Scrape', jobs_create_path, :method=>:post, :remote => true, :class => "btn btn-primary"  %>
```

Your path may be different and want to take some kind of value, like the `:job_type => "StatsAll"` you had in there, but I'm not exactly sure.

You see that part for the `:remote => true`? That is where the special AJAX stuff happens. If you want something more complicated though, it can be (but it's a ton more work). But this is the easy way for it to start going to create.js.erb.

Make a create.js.erb in your app/views/jobs for the button where you can escape_javascript to rerender the button (like you said you wanted to do). After it rerenders, you can also do this same process for the other feature you wanted to include:

```
$('#create_button').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "shared/create_job") %>'); // May need to use whatever locals you need to in here.
```

This should do it, since all it seems you want to do is just call a function and then stay on the page, but change the button.

Also, for the above code, this assumes you're using a partial for the button. This is so you don't have to completely re-render/reload the page, just the partial that corresponds with the button.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found that I can specify which page to go to by just doing a `redirect_to` at the end of the action. Like so...

```
  def create
    # Do stuf...
    redirect_to 'admin/#page-i-was-at'
  end
```

Comment: This approach will force browser to reload page. More elegant is to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for your `create` action.

```
def create    
  call_rake :import_records, :job_type => params[:job_type]
  redirect_to :back, notice: "Import is executing..."
end
```